# Where did the package software.amazon.awssdk.core.auth.policy go in the AWS Java SDK V2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk

I found this piece of documentation for a way to build policies for accessing S3 Buckets (among other things) programmatically, but I can't find seem to find it. (Based on the file path, I would've guessed that it would be in either auth or sdk-core).

Has this been deprecated and moved somewhere else? There seems to be a similar (possibly equivalent) version in the V1 version of the SDK but would rather use V2 if possible.

Link to documentation: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0/software/amazon/awssdk/core/auth/policy/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are still there, in the AWS SDK:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/test/test-utils/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/core/auth/policy

But they are probably test classes (look at the full path). So, they may never meant to be a part of the public API. The Javadocs were "fixed" between [`2.1.3`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.1.3/software/amazon/awssdk/core/auth/policy/package-summary.html) and [`2.1.4`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.1.4/software/amazon/awssdk/core/auth/policy/package-summary.html).

If you are looking for those classes, they reside in [this articact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/test-utils). Add it to your project, and you'll get them.

Answer (score 0):

The Github repo for the V2 AWS Java SDK has a feature request for official support: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/39

Please +1 and/or comment if you are missing this feature!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this, I'll go and comment

Answer (score 0):

It is in maven, but with "test" scope.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/test-utils

Answer (score 0):

Following the @cenedhryn link, the new dependency (since July 2023) for this library is [AWS Java SDK :: IAM :: Policy Builder](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/iam-policy-builder)

The new names are `IamPolicy`, `IamPrincipal`, `IamStatement`, etc.