# AWS S3 Bucket Policy Java API v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can I set AWS S3 Bucket Policy programmatically using Java API v2?

In the API docs, I see how to set policy by the JSON file, but I do not see the right way how to do that programmatically. But API v1 allows doing that.

Comment: You can use [`PutBucketPolicy()`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#putBucketPolicy-java.util.function.Consumer-)

Comment: ok, I know this method. Inside this method I should put PutBucketPolicyRequest.
Example: PutBucketPolicyRequest policyReq = PutBucketPolicyRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .policy("jsonFile")
                    .build();
But for this case, I should have a JSON file. But what about creating policy withount external JSONs?

Comment: Bucket Policies are written in JSON, so it requires you to provide the JSON. If you want to 'construct' the JSON, you'll need to do that in your own code. You can pass the policy as a String -- I don't think it needs to come from a file.

Comment: ok, thank you John as always you helped me)). P.S. I think good to have a builder for creating JSON directly in the code. I don't want to construct JSON for PutBucketPolicyRequest as a String objects. I think I will make my own java object, for example CustomBucketPolicy with necessary fields ("Action", "Resource", "Effect" and so on). I see that it was in the API v1, correct?

Comment: I'm not a Java person, so I'm not sure how it worked in API v1. But it sounds like you know what to do, so give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and after thousands of hours of searching, I was able to find the answer. They decided to put it in `test-utils`

A similar question:
[Where did the package software.amazon.awssdk.core.auth.policy go in the AWS Java SDK V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70989658/where-did-the-package-software-amazon-awssdk-core-auth-policy-go-in-the-aws-java)

The artifact you need:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/test-utils/2.23.7

source code on GitHub:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/test/test-utils/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/core/auth/policy

Documentation on it:
https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/2.0.0-preview-11/software/amazon/awssdk/core/auth/policy/Policy.html